# Do you speak out /k/ and / ɪ/ simultaneously in 'outbreak in'?

Tags: pronunciation

> The announcement that Canberra-based Aspen Medical will step into the front line of Australia's response to the Ebola **outbreak in** West Africa has been widely welcomed. 
>  (Aussie [ABC](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4122550.htm), its audio is [here](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/485))

Does he put a gap at all between /k/ in *outbreak* and / ɪ/ in *in*? Or does he pronounce the two sounds simultaneously? What I want to know is if you put a gap between an NP - *the Ebola outbreak* - and a modifier - *in West Africa*. If there isn’t a gap, you, even though using your own mother tongue, could be confused. If there was a gap, I might not have listened to this sentence this much, over about two hours. Still, I don’t sense the gap, and that bothers me to follow him up.

Comment: I haven't listened to the audio clip, but it wouldn't surprise me if _outbreak in_ sounds identical to _outbray kin_. In English, aurel oddities like that are not uncommon. C.S. Lewis used two in his _Chronicles of Narnia_ series, when the faun hails Lucy as being from "the far land of Spare Oom where eternal summer reigns around the bright city of War Drobe," having misheard _spare room_ and _wardrobe_. And many have wondered why Jimi Hendrix was singing, "Excuse me, while I kiss this guy," when he was in reality crooning a homophone: "Excuse me, while I kiss the sky."

Comment: There isn't a gap between /k/ and /i/ indeed. The /k/ sound is from 6.09 to 6.165 in the clip I recorded from your audio. You can see my screenshots [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MJJqY.png) and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S1wi2.png). (I moved [my comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18750571#18750571) to the chat room 'cause I want to see more answers by others.)

Comment: While I can imagine a pronunciation with a gap, and one without a gap (where the latter would sound absolutely natural to me), I really have a difficult time imagining the amazing verbal capabilities of someone who would manage to produce a consonant _and_ a vowel sound **simultaneously**!

Comment: @oerkelens Try pronouncing "fu". Now, make the vowel voiceless, and try *ffffuuuuuu*. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I seriously doubt my capability to produce any but a few voiceless vowels... there _are_ languages that have them, but even then I dare anyone to sustain a prolonged voiceless vowel sound. If you pronounce _peculiar_, the first _e_ may be produced voicelessly, but it is still produced _after_ the _p_ consonant!

Comment: @DamkerngT. .phn and .lab both are typed by you or by the gadget automatically? If the latter, what configuration do I have to choose in the gadget?

Comment: It was done manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final phoneme of a word and the initial phoneme of the word that follows it *can* be spoken in such rapid succession that they seem to 'merge'. If they're vowels, they 'elide'. The degree to which they do so depends on the positions of the tongue, lips, jaw, etc. that are required to produce the sounds. When the sounds require rather different positionings of the 'speech apparatus', they tend to be produced as discrete sounds; when little or no repositioning is required, they tend to unite (in everyday speech).

> The brook trout makes its home in cold moving water.
>
> Flightless birds seem to walk quickly.